# Can't get over 50% max. theoretical performance on matrix multiply

Tags: c, optimization, matrix, openmp, sse

**Problem**

I am learning about HPC and code optimization. I attempt to replicate the results in Goto's seminal matrix multiplication paper (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/pingali/CS378/2008sp/papers/gotoPaper.pdf). Despite my best efforts, I cannot get over ~50% maximum theoretical CPU performance.

**Background**

See related issues here ([Optimized 2x2 matrix multiplication: Slow assembly versus fast SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790842/optimized-2x2-matrix-multiplication-slow-assembly-versus-fast-simd)), including info about my hardware

**What I have attempted**

This related paper (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/pubs/blis3_ipdps14.pdf) has a good description of Goto's algorithmic structure. I provide my source code below.

**My question**

I am asking for general help. I have been working on this for far too long, have tried many different algorithms, inline assembly, inner kernels of various sizes (2x2, 4x4, 2x8, ..., mxn with m and n large), yet ***I cannot seem to break 50% CPU Gflops***. This is purely for education purposes and not a homework.

**Source Code**

Hopefully is understandable. Please ask if not. I set up the macro structure (for loops) as described in the 2nd paper above. I pack the matrices as discussed in either paper and shown graphically in Figure 11 here (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/pubs/BLISTOMSrev2.pdf). My inner kernel computes 2x8 blocks, as this seems to be the optimal computation for Nehalem architecture (see GotoBLAS source code - kernels). The inner kernel is based on the concept of calculating rank-1 updates as described here (http://code.google.com/p/blis/source/browse/config/template/kernels/3/bli_gemm_opt_mxn.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdint.h>


// define some prefetch functions
#define PREFETCHNTA(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_NTA)

#define PREFETCHT0(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_T0)

#define PREFETCHT1(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_T1)

#define PREFETCHT2(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_T2)

// define a min function
#ifndef min
    #define min( a, b ) ( ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b) )
#endif

// zero a matrix
void zeromat(double *C, int n)
{
    int i = n;
    while (i--) {
        int j = n;
        while (j--) {
            *(C + i*n + j) = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

// compute a 2x8 block from (2 x kc) x (kc x 8) matrices
inline void 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64))) dgemm_2x8_sse(
                int k,
                const double* restrict a1, const int cs_a,
                const double* restrict b1, const int rs_b,
                      double* restrict c11, const int rs_c
                )
{

    register __m128d xmm1, xmm4, //
                    r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15; // accumulators

    // 10 registers declared here

    r8 = _mm_xor_pd(r8,r8); // ab
    r9 = _mm_xor_pd(r9,r9);
    r10 = _mm_xor_pd(r10,r10);
    r11 = _mm_xor_pd(r11,r11);

    r12 = _mm_xor_pd(r12,r12); // ab + 8
    r13 = _mm_xor_pd(r13,r13);
    r14 = _mm_xor_pd(r14,r14);
    r15 = _mm_xor_pd(r15,r15);

        // PREFETCHT2(b1,0);
        // PREFETCHT2(b1,64);



    //int l = k;
    while (k--) {

        //PREFETCHT0(a1,0); // fetch 64 bytes from a1

            // i = 0
            xmm1 = _mm_load1_pd(a1);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r8 = _mm_add_pd(r8,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 2);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r9 = _mm_add_pd(r9,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 4);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r10 = _mm_add_pd(r10,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 6);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r11 = _mm_add_pd(r11,xmm4);

            //
            // i = 1
            xmm1 = _mm_load1_pd(a1 + 1);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r12 = _mm_add_pd(r12,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 2);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r13 = _mm_add_pd(r13,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 4);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r14 = _mm_add_pd(r14,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 6);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r15 = _mm_add_pd(r15,xmm4);

        a1 += cs_a;
        b1 += rs_b;

        //PREFETCHT2(b1,0);
        //PREFETCHT2(b1,64);

    }

        // copy result into C

        PREFETCHT0(c11,0);
        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r8);
        _mm_store_pd(c11,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 2);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r9);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 2,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 4);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r10);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 4,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 6);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r11);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 6,xmm1);

        c11 += rs_c;

        PREFETCHT0(c11,0);
        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r12);
        _mm_store_pd(c11,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 2);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r13);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 2,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 4);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r14);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 4,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 6);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r15);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 6,xmm1);

}

// packs a matrix into rows of slivers
inline void 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64))) rpack(        double* restrict dst, 
          const double* restrict src, 
            const int kc, const int mc, const int mr, const int n)
{
    double tmp[mc*kc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    double* restrict ptr = &tmp[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < mc; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < kc; ++j)
            *ptr++ = *(src + i*n + j);

    ptr = &tmp[0];

    //const int inc_dst = mr*kc;
    for (int k = 0; k < mc; k+=mr)
        for (int j = 0; j < kc; ++j)
            for (int i = 0; i < mr*kc; i+=kc)
                *dst++ = *(ptr + k*kc + j + i);

}

// packs a matrix into columns of slivers
inline void 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64)))  cpack(double* restrict dst, 
                const double* restrict src, 
                const int nc, 
                const int kc, 
                const int nr, 
                const int n)
{
    double tmp[kc*nc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    double* restrict ptr = &tmp[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < kc; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < nc; ++j)
            *ptr++ = *(src + i*n + j);

    ptr = &tmp[0];

    // const int inc_k = nc/nr;
    for (int k = 0; k < nc; k+=nr)
        for (int j = 0; j < kc*nc; j+=nc)
            for (int i = 0; i < nr; ++i)
                *dst++ = *(ptr + k + i + j);

}

void blis_dgemm_ref(
        const int n,
        const double* restrict A,
        const double* restrict B,
        double* restrict C,
        const int mc,
        const int nc,
        const int kc
    )
{
    int mr = 2;
    int nr = 8;
    double locA[mc*kc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    double locB[kc*nc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    int ii,jj,kk,i,j;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) shared(A,B,C) private(ii,jj,kk,i,j,locA,locB)
    {//use all threads in parallel
        #pragma omp for
        // partitions C and B into wide column panels
        for ( jj = 0; jj < n; jj+=nc) {
        // A and the current column of B are partitioned into col and row panels
            for ( kk = 0; kk < n; kk+=kc) {
                cpack(locB, B + kk*n + jj, nc, kc, nr, n);
                // partition current panel of A into blocks
                for ( ii = 0; ii < n; ii+=mc) {
                    rpack(locA, A + ii*n + kk, kc, mc, mr, n);
                    for ( i = 0; i < min(n-ii,mc); i+=mr) {
                        for ( j = 0; j < min(n-jj,nc); j+=nr) {
                            // inner kernel that compues 2 x 8 block
                            dgemm_2x8_sse( kc,
                                       locA + i*kc          ,  mr,
                                       locB + j*kc          ,  nr,
                                       C + (i+ii)*n + (j+jj),  n );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

double compute_gflops(const double time, const int n)
{
    // computes the gigaflops for a square matrix-matrix multiplication
    double gflops;
    gflops = (double) (2.0*n*n*n)/time/1.0e9;
    return(gflops);
}

// ******* MAIN ********//
void main() {
    clock_t time1, time2;
    double time3;
    double gflops;
    const int trials = 10;

    int nmax = 4096;
    printf("%10s %10s\n","N","Gflops/s");

    int mc = 128;
    int kc = 256;
    int nc = 128;

    for (int n = kc; n <= nmax; n+=kc) { //assuming kc is the max dim
        double *A = NULL;
        double *B = NULL;
        double *C = NULL;

        A = _mm_malloc (n*n * sizeof(*A),64);
        B = _mm_malloc (n*n * sizeof(*B),64);
        C = _mm_malloc (n*n * sizeof(*C),64);

        srand(time(NULL));

        // Create the matrices
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                A[i*n + j] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
                B[i*n + j] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
                //D[j*n + i] = B[i*n + j]; // Transpose
                C[i*n + j] = 0.0;
            }
        }

            // warmup
            zeromat(C,n);
            blis_dgemm_ref(n,A,B,C,mc,nc,kc);
            zeromat(C,n);
            time2 = 0;
            for (int count = 0; count < trials; count++){// iterations per experiment here
                    time1 = clock();
                    blis_dgemm_ref(n,A,B,C,mc,nc,kc);
                    time2 += clock() - time1;
                    zeromat(C,n);
                }
            time3 = (double)(time2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/trials;
            gflops = compute_gflops(time3, n);
            printf("%10d %10f\n",n,gflops);

        _mm_free(A);
        _mm_free(B);
        _mm_free(C);

        }

    printf("tests are done\n");
}
```

**EDIT 1**

OS = Win 7 64 bit

Compiler = gcc 4.8.1, but 32 bit and mingw (32 bit also. I am working to get a "non-install" version of mingw64 so I can generate faster code/work with more XMM registers, etc. If anyone has a link to a mingw64 installation that is similar in fashion to `mingw-get` please post. My work computer has way too many admin restrictions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I disagree, if I am barely getting 50% performance then that means I am missing something conceptually, which is what I am asking for help with. I will post there as well though.

Comment: Crossposted to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52140/cant-get-more-than-50-cpu-gflops-in-matrix-multiplication-cross-post-from-so

Comment: Comment out all the prefetch stuff for now - it typically does more harm than good on modern CPUs.

Comment: I have tried that as well, including the various combinations you see commented out. I get a small performance boost prefetching `c11` but I'm still very far behind whether I prefetch or not. I tried to use the prefetching techniques that you can find in various assembly-coded BLAS inner kernels.

Comment: I have been looking into this off and on for about a year.  My own code using AVX get's about 75% of the peak flops now.  Give me a few days and I'll try and give a good answer.

Comment: What size matrices are you testing on?  You will only get peak flops on large matrices.  For example with the Intel MKL it gets 80% or so for 1024x1024 matrices and about 94% for 4096x4096 matrices on my Sandy Bridge System.

Comment: I have one suggestion for now.  Your system has 2 cores and hyper-threading.  Set your number of threads in OpenMP to 2 not 4.  Hyper-threading is useful when code has a lot of CPU stalls (which most code does), but you code should not be stalling.  Hyper-threading gives much worse results on my system.

Comment: What is the efficiency for only one core (compile without OpenMP)?

Comment: Yikes!  You're using the clock function!  You can't use that to time multi-threaded code on Linux.  It does not report the wall time on Linux.  Use `omp_get_wtime()`.

Comment: You should add OpenMP to your tags (remove one of the others like blas).  OpenMP is easy to use.  It's much easier to get going with than writing SSE intrinsics.  But intrinsics once you learn them make sense.  However, OpenMP is a black box and it's actually difficult to understand what's going on often.  Particularly with the scheduling of threads.

Comment: Have you tried running something much simpler (say a vector dot product) to confirm your understanding of the "speed limit" of your processor? In other words - can you create _any_ code that you think hits the speed limit? Because things like looping take time...

Comment: If your matrix dimensions are large, you shouldn't use sizes that are powers of 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060985/why-huge-performance-hit-2048x2048-array-versus-2047x2047 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264970/why-is-my-program-slow-when-looping-over-exactly-8192-elements?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905760/matrix-multiplication-small-difference-in-matrix-size-large-difference-in-timi

Comment: also [Why is transposing a matrix of 512x512 much slower than transposing a matrix of 513x513?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413855/why-is-transposing-a-matrix-of-512x512-much-slower-than-transposing-a-matrix-of)

Comment: I am running a series of tests, in the code above the variable `int nmax` sets the maximum size of the square matrices being multiplied, 4096 in this case. The tests start from matrices of size equal to the block size and increments them by block size up to `nmax`. @Floris, I will attempt your suggestion and see how fast I can make a dot product. From my understanding of BLAS codes, levels 1 and 2 are typically much slower than level 3 (matrix multiplication) which builds upon such things as dot products. @Phuc, most of my matrices are not powers of 2.

Comment: @ Phuc, I don't think the powers of 2 thing would be an issue anyway, because I am blocking my matrices to fit in the L1 and L2 caches.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, matmul is correct.  See section 9.10 in Agner Fog's Optimizing C++ manual.  He discusses the problem you are referring to due to cache aliasing.  He presents two solutions.  One using loop tiling (blocking) and the other using non-temporal stores.  The tiling method works better.  I'm not saying that cache-aliasing is not a problem with loop blocking but the drastic performance drops do go away.

Comment: Can you please state/add the OS and the compiler you are using?  Your code is using GCC constructs but you say you are running in windows so that is confusing.  Are you using MinGW-w64? Also can you add a performance table (at least for large n).  Both for single-threaded and mulch-threaded performance?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about your packing.  It looks like you're doing `rpack` too often.  It only depends on `ii` and `kk` so you redo it for each `jj` iteration.  I don't think you need to redo it for each `jj` iteration.  What's your efficiency if you comment out `rpack` (just as a test)?

Comment: OS and compiler added as an EDIT in the main post. I will post a performance table with 1 and 2 threads, and with and without packing routines, as an "answer" shortly.

Comment: Hi @Zboson thanks for posting your codes, I am looking at them now. For the packing operation, I am not packing the full matrix but rather I am packing the cached blocks. Unfortunately I do not see any way to avoid `rpack` being called repeatedly for each `jj` except by using `if (jj == 0) {rpack()}`. A loop interchange would just cause `cpack` to be called repeatedly for each `ii`. I am also going to move the `zeromat()` (matrix zeroing) operation into my GEMM function to make the comparison more fair (`dgemm.f` has that op. inside itself).

Comment: @matmul, what's wrong with `if (jj = 0) {rpack()}`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I was just trying to see fist if there was a way to do it by just loop rearrangement or shifting around code.

Comment: Another comment is that you could trying fusing your loops. You're using large block sizes so the load distribution for threads is not always good.  You can fuse manually or use `collapse` with OpenMP.  Speaking of which you can clean up your OpenMP code a bunch.  You can use `parallel for` and counter initialization in the loops (in C99 and C++) and then avoid all the shared and private declarations (see my code).  But that won't change your result but fusing might.

Comment: @Zboson, I just realized you are operating on type `float`s. I wonder how the performance would change for me if I also used `float` rather than `double`. I will take some time to write a version of my code optimized for `float` matrices to see.

Comment: @matmul, I would stick to double since that's what you have optimized for (I optimized for float).  The size of float or double will effect the block size you use to fit in the cache.

Comment: Something very strange happens when I use `if (jj = 0) {rpack()}`. I am getting the wrong answer with this condition. I commented out OpenMP just to be sure it wasn't a parallelization issue and it still happens. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: `if (jj = 0) {rpack()}` causes the packing to only be performed wen `jj == 0` so when `jj > 0` and `ii` and `kk` reset, it won't allow the cached block of A, `locA`, to be updated. So I guess I have no choice here but to leave it the way it was.

Comment: I have no idea how OpenMP works with MinGW.  It probably is based on Windows Threads.  Maybe you can use Knoppix at work on a USB?  That way you can run Linux with GCC without dual booting.

Comment: @matmul, I missed your later comments about rpack.  You should allocate a buffer the size of your matrix and do `rpack` for each block and store that.  That will get the correct result without OpenMP.  With OpenMP it's more tricky.  You could do what I do which is to do the packing (at least for A) outside of the multiplication.  Why don't you try that?  What you're doing now repacking the same thing every `jj` iteration is not optimal.

Comment: @Zboson, I have made a lot of changes and I will make a new question since the code has changed a lot. I will link shortly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071622/replicating-blas-matrix-multiplication-performance-can-i-match-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Packing**

You appear to be packing the block of the `A` matrix too often.  You do

```
rpack(locA, A + ii*n + kk, kc, mc, mr, n);
```

But this only depends on `ii` and `kk` and not on `jj` but it's inside the inner loop on `jj` so you repack the same thing for each iteration of `jj`.  I don't think that's necessary.  In my code I do the packing before the matrix multiplication.  Probably it's more efficient to pack inside the the matrix multiplication while the values are still in the cache but it's trickier to do that. But packing is a O(n^2) operation and matrix multiplication is a O(n^3) operation so it's not very inefficient to pack outside of the matrix multiplication for large matrices (I know that from testing as well - commenting out the packing only changes the efficiency by a few percent).  However, by repacking with `rpack` each `jj` iteration you have effectively made it an O(n^3) operation.

**Wall Time**

You want the wall time.  [On Unix the clock() function does not return the wall time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874214/measure-execution-time-in-c-openmp-code) (though it does on Windows with MSVC).  It returns the cumulative time for each thread.  This is one of the most common errors I have seen on SO for OpenMP.

Use `omp_get_wtime()` to get the wall time.

Note that I don't know how the `clock()` function works with MinGW or MinGW-w64 (they are separate projects). MinGW links to MSVCRT so I would guess that `clock()` with MinGW returns the wall time as it does with MSVC.  However, MinGW-w64 does not link to MSVCRT (as far as I understand it links to something like glibc). It's possible that `clock()` in MinGW-w64 performs the same as `clock()` does with Unix.

**Hyper Threading**

Hyper threading works well for code that stalls the CPU often.  That's actually the majority of code because it's very difficult to write code that does not stall the CPU.  That's why Intel invented Hyper Threading.  It's easier to task switch and give the CPU something else to do than to optimize the code.  However, for code that is highly optimized hyper-threading can actually give worse results.  In my own matrix multiplication code that's certainly the case.  Set the number of threads to the number of physical cores you have (two in your case).

**My Code**

Below is my code.  I did not include the `inner64` function here. You can find it at [Difference in performance between MSVC and GCC for highly optimized matrix multplication code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134279/difference-in-performance-between-msvc-and-gcc-for-highly-optimized-matrix-multp/21257842#21257842) (with the obnoxious and misleading name of `AddDot4x4_vec_block_8wide`)

I wrote this code before reading the Goto paper and also before reading Agner Fog's optimization manuals.  You appear to reorder/pack the matrices in the main loop.  That probably makes more sense.  I don't think I reorder them the same way you do and also I only reorder one of the input matrices (B) and not both as you do.

The performance of this code on my system (Xeon E5-1620@3.6) with Linux and GCC is about 75% of the peak for this matrix size (4096x4096).  Intel's MKL get's about 94% of the peak on my system for this matrix size so there is clearly room for improvement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

extern "C" void inner64(const float *a, const float *b, float *c);
void (*fp)(const float *a, const float *b, float *c) = inner64;

void reorder(float * __restrict a, float * __restrict b, int n, int bs) {
    int nb = n/bs;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<nb; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<nb; j++) {
            for(int i2=0; i2<bs; i2++) {
                for(int j2=0; j2<bs; j2++) {
                    b[bs*bs*(nb*i+j) + bs*i2+j2]= a[bs*(i*n+j) + i2*n + j2];    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

inline void gemm_block(float * __restrict a, float * __restrict b, float * __restrict c, int n, int n2) {
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++) {
        fp(&a[i*n], b, &c[i*n]);
    }
}

void gemm(float * __restrict a, float * __restrict b, float * __restrict c, int n, int bs) {
    int nb = n/bs;
    float *b2 = (float*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n,64);
    reorder(b,b2,n,bs);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<nb; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<nb; j++) {
            for(int k=0; k<nb; k++) {
                gemm_block(&a[bs*(i*n+k)],&b2[bs*bs*(k*nb+j)],&c[bs*(i*n+j)], n, bs);
            }
        }
    }
    _mm_free(b2);
}

int main() {
    float peak = 1.0f*8*4*2*3.69f;
    const int n = 4096;
    float flop = 2.0f*n*n*n*1E-9f;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    float *a = (float*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n,64);
    float *b = (float*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n,64);
    float *c = (float*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n,64);
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++) {
        a[i] = 1.0f*rand()/RAND_MAX;
        b[i] = 1.0f*rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }

    gemm(a,b,c,n,64); //warm OpenMP up
    while(1) {
        for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++) c[i] = 0;
        double dtime = omp_get_wtime();
        gemm(a,b,c,n,64);   
        dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
        printf("time %.2f s, efficiency %.2f%%\n", dtime, 100*flop/dtime/peak);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dunno whether the newest CPUs can avoid using Hyper Threading if you only use X CPUs instead of X x 2. From my understanding, if you have Hyper Threading turned on in your BIOS, your CPUs are 50% slower than normal. That could indeed be his culprit if he has HT turned on. HT is great for servers that handle Web Sites and need "more processors," rather than "faster processors."

Comment: @AlexisWilke, the cores in your CPU are not any slower with hyper-threading enabled.  The OP can avoid hyper threading by have one thread for each core.  The problem is getting OpenMP to do that for you.  Normally it should but the OP may need to bind the threads to each core.

Comment: My tests on the first few CPUs that had Hyper Threading would clearly show when you were using exactly 1 single CPU, it would be twice slower than without Hyper Threading. (I had to compile code for 30 min. with HT, 15 min. without, quite a good test! At the time Visual Studio would not use multiple threads. Unfortunately, the app I was working on required HT... that was with Xeons around 2006/2007.)

Comment: Z boson, thanks for your attention. I have HT turned off in the BIOS, windows task manager shows 2 CPU charts (not 4 as before I turned HT off): 2 cores, 2 threads. I will change the 4 to 2 in OMP. I don't think my CPU is throttled. I made it use 100% CPU in the power settings (Windows 7) ... so I guess that also settles the `clock()` issue. I had a friend run my code on Linux and use `perf` and it shows around 33% front end stalls, but not much of anything else. I will try to use `perfmon` on Windows to try to get some info, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: @Zboson, would you mind pasting your code? I;m interested in how you blocked your matrices and I would also like to see your inner kernel so I compare to mine.

Comment: @matmul, I added some information to my answer about `clock()` with MinGW and MinGw-w64.  I don't know if clock() performs the same as with MSVC with them.  My guess is that MinGW-w64's clock() works the same as on Unix.  Incidentally, could you add the compiler and OS you use to your question please.  That's useful information for people.

Comment: @matmul, if you have disabled hyper-threading but are still using four threads with two cores than that's even worse.  That's effectively like software hyper-threading.  Set your number of threads to the number of physical cores (or use the default which if hyper-threading is off will be two anyway).

Comment: @matmul, I forgot to mention this but I did test your later code and discovered that the `rpack` which I said you did too often actually was not a problem. I'm sure you already know that now. I'm not going to change my answer though until I have seen your tutorial.